# Double variable to setlatitude NullPointerException error

Tags: android

`NullPointerException` this error happens when i try to set `location2.setLatitude(latitudeclick);`

I test the app and i receive when i click the value out of latitudeclick

```
@Override
public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
      if (places.getCount() == 1) {
          localizacao =  (places.get(0).getLatLng());
          Double latitudeclick = localizacao.latitude;
          Double longitudeclick = localizacao.longitude;
          Location location2 = null;
          location2.setLatitude(latitudeclick);
          location2.setLatitude(longitudeclick);
       }
}
```

Comment: `location2` is null. Try `location = new Location()`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Location location2 = null;
```

to

```
Location location2 = new Location();
```